# Tell Superview to ignore touch events?

Tags: ios, superview

I am adding a subview to my superview and I need to know how to tell the superview to ignore touch events so that the only view receiving touch events, is the subview.
How would this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the superview to `NO`:

```
view.superview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```